# Server error: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8081` resulted in a `503 Service Unavailable` response:

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to build a reccomendationn engine for my website.I am using PHP with Laravel for the back-end.I want to build a reccomendation engine so I decided to use Nodejs for it.....

The nodejs reccomendation engine uses GER and produces reccomendations.When I go to 
`localhost:8081` **in my browser** I get what I expect **perfectly**.My site is running on localhost:8000 so I need to bring in the recommendations from localhost:8081 to `localhost:8000/reccomendations'.For this I decided to use **Guzzle**.

This is my controller(a part of it) in laravel:

```
//RECCOMMENDATION SYSTEM

    public function showReccPosts(){
        $person='alice';

        //The URL you want to send a cURL proxy request to.
        $client = new Client();
        $request = $client->get('http://127.0.0.1:8081', [
            'config' => [
                'curl' => [
                    'CURLOPT_PROXY' => 'asoju.unilag.edu.ng:3128',
                    'CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL' => 1,
                ]
               ]
            ]);
        $result = $request->getBody()->getContents();

       return view('reccomended.index',compact('result'));

    }
```

If I try it with an external website like google.com it works perfectly.
But if i try it with 127.0.0.1:8000 it gives me this error:

```
GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ServerException (503)
Server error: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8081` resulted in a `503 Service Unavailable` response: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <html><head> <meta type="copy (truncated...)
```

I have no idea what is going on.503 is  a generic error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had to tell curl to ignore the proxy as in:

```
        // Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:8080/?name=$name",
    CURLOPT_PROXY => '',//IGNORE THE PROXY THAT IS NORMALLY USED FOR INTERNET ACCESS
]);
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$results = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```